# pdf2text convertor plugin return not readable formate

Tags: php

I have used this plugin it is working fine but for some file return a different(Not readable) formate. please suggest me what is the problem and how to fix it.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: $pdf = new Pdf2Text();
 $pdf->setFilename("/var/www/html/rpkfiles/Metro.pdf");
 $pdf->decodePDF();
 $prd_str = $pdf->output();

Comment: Share your code and show return data - use `dd`

Comment: above i have mentioned my call.

Comment: @sradha show the page plugin, with you use

Comment: https://github.com/asika32764/php-pdf-2-text/blob/master/src/Pdf2text.php

Comment: this is the source code for the plugin which i have used.

Comment: @sradha Check this solution `$reader = new \Asika\Pdf2text;
$output = $reader->decode($fileName);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178001/discussion-between-sradha-and-adam-wadolkowski).

Answer (score 0):

Pdf2Text does not work with some pdf files or it gives text which is not readable so try another class which works well in converting pdf to text

Use PdfToText class [PdftoText](https://github.com/christian-vigh-phpclasses/PdfToText/blob/master/PdfToText.phpclass)

```
include ('PdfToText.php') ;
$pdf = new PdfToText ('pdf_files/chronopost1.pdf');

$pdf_text = $pdf->Text;
// cleaning text
$pdf_text = str_replace("\n", " ", $pdf_text);
$pdf_text = preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $pdf_text);
$pdf_text = trim($pdf_text);

echo "OUTPUT: " . $pdf_text;
```

Comment: Please consider my answer if that helped you